# Why does AWS Lambda not able to find my main.py?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to upload a python lambda function via a zip file. I copied all of my python files into a directory called "lambda", installed all of the libraries directly into that directory, did `chmod -R 755 .` to make sure all of those files are executable, and then zipped the directory with `zip -r ../analysis.zip .`

The file that holds my lambda function is called "main.py" and the lambda function is called "handler", so by AWS Lambda convention, I set the file it should be looking for to `main.handler` in the AWS Lambda page. I check my cloudwatch logs for this lambda function and still get an error saying aws cannot find the main module and also cannot find some regex._regex module as well.

This is the official error:
`[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'regex._regex'`

Does anyone know what can be the problem? I have deployed aws lambda functions before using the same process and this is the first time I am getting this issue.

Comment: The runtime is saying it cannot fine the module `regex._regex`, did you include the dependencies in your zip?

Comment: Also, how did you prepare the deployment package? Using same python version as used in lambda?

Comment: Did you zip the whole directory or just the contents of the directory. I think you need to zip all the contents of directory including your dependencies.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html

Comment: @yorodm I used the library "re" and pip installed it directly into the lambda directory.

Comment: @Marcin yes both the deployment package and lambda Python are the same version.

Comment: @DineshKumar just the contents (i.e. the Python files and libraries). I have been using that same zip command/lambda directory for other lambda functions and they have worked. I will take a look at the article thanks.

Comment: I've found [this](https://github.com/Miserlou/lambda-packages/issues/70) . I'm not sure if it's 100% related to your case but I think it's worth take a look

Answer (score 1):

Lambda operates on a Python function/method not at the file. So the function handler must point to a actual function/method not a file.

So within your `main.py` file, there must be a function e.g. `test_function`, and your handler has to be `main.test_function`. The name of the function in AWS is irrelevant to the function.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's what I have. I have my main.py file and within that my lambda(event, context). In AWS I have it set to look for main.handler

Comment: you mean handler(event, context) ?

Comment: Yeah my bad the function is handler(event,contxt): in main.py

Answer (score 0):

By the description and error message your naming convention seems right.

The error message indicates that you're missing the regex module. However, from your description you seem to have packaged the dependancies correctly.

Usually, it would then be a case of a runtime miss match. However, I have had struggles with regex and lambda when runtimes do match. By default now, I don't go above python 3.6 at the moment. I have struggled with other dependancies on lambda, such as pickle, on higher versions recently. Whilst everything seems to operate fine on 3.6.

I got rid of the regex error on lambda with python 3.6 by downloading the taar.gz file from pypi and running setup.py... rather than pip3 install. It's a bit of pain, but it worked.